# ajax: extract json object from array of json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

JSON (inside array from api):

```
[{"id":"001", "name":"john", "age":"40"}, {"id":"002", "name":"jane", "age":"30"}]
```

Ajax:

```
  $.ajax({                                      
  url: 'interface_API.php',                                                              
  dataType: 'json',                    
  success: function(data)         
  {
    for(var i in data){
        var row = data[i];

        var id = row[0];            
        var name = row[1];
        var age = row[2];

    $('#output').append("<tr width='50%'><td>"+id+"</td><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+age+"</td></tr>"); 
    }
  } 
});
```

The API uses this to construct:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($output)){
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($output)){
         $json[] = $row;
     }
}
```

However my Output is 'undefined' repeated for each `.append`

How do i extract each json object from the array & append to the page?

Comment: Have you tried using `console.log` to see what `data` actually contains?

Comment: You should be using a regular for loop for an array, and to access the objects properties you'd do `row.id` etc. not `row[0]`.

Comment: do you get proper reponse/output of interface_API.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
var id = row[0];            
var name = row[1];
var age = row[2];
```

to this:

```
var id = row['id'];            
var name = row['name'];
var age = row['age'];
```

or this:

```
var id = row.id;
var name = row.name;
var age = row.age;
```

---

Because you already looped in here:

```
for(var i in data){
    var row = data[i]; // <----here
```

so you just required to reference it with keys in the js object.

Comment: i will accept this answer after the timeout as you were first to answer. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can change the for loop like this:

```
$.ajax({                                      
  url: 'interface_API.php',                                                              
  dataType: 'json',                    
  success: function(data)         
  {
    for(var i in data){
        var row = data[i];

        var id = row.id;            
        var name = row.name;
        var age = row.age;

$('#output').append("<tr width='50%'><td>"+id+"</td><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+age+"</td></tr>"); 
}
} 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please use the key to identify the json Object while retrieving

```
var list=[
        {"id":"1","text":"test1"},
        {"id":"2","text":"test2"},
        {"id":"3","text":"test3"},
        {"id":"4","text":"test4"}

         ]


    alert(list[2].id)
```